# How extracting results using custom function in lapply works

Tags: r, lapply, lm

I am trying to extract regression coefficients using the function below;

```
## customized function to return coef as matrix

cust_lm<- function(varname, data){ 
y<-data[,varname]   
coefOLS<- as.matrix(coef(summary(lm(y~x))));            
}
```

I want to run regression using different dependent variables (independent variable remain the same) each time with this function. I am using `lapply` for the same.

```
## artificial data
x<-rnorm(100,5,3)
ydata<-data.frame(y1=rnorm(100), y2=rnorm(100))

## running regressions together and storing as list
list<-lapply(names(ydata)[1:2], function(x) cust_lm(x, ydata))
```

I'm getting the desired result where `list[[1]]` is nothing but `coef(summary(lm(ydata[,1]~x)))` and `list[[2]]` is equal to `coef(summary(lm(ydata[,2]~x)))`.

I have written this with the help of several SO posts sometime back. Now I want to decipher my custom function to know how it works and also I'm not very clear about `lapply`.

I have already created the custom function with the arguments requiring as, `(varname, data)` and again I'm giving `cust_lm(x, data)` as an argument in `lapply`. Is it right thing to do?

Is it right if I give, `list<-lapply(names(ydata)[1:2], function(z) cust_lm(z, data))` instead?. I'm quite confused on this. Any help/resources are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always try to break it down bit by bit.
The first iteration of `lapply` would call `cust_lm('a', ydata)`. Let's take a look:

```
cust_lm('y1', ydata)
#                 Estimate Std. Error     t value  Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)  0.006170844 0.22234415  0.02775357 0.9779151
# x           -0.004470560 0.03960525 -0.11287797 0.9103582
```

In your code, the name `data` is the variable name *inside the function*. So when you specify `list<-lapply(names(ydata)[1:2], function(z) cust_lm(z, data))`, R will be looking for a variable named `data` when the line is called. So this is *wrong*. Calling it with `list<-lapply(names(ydata)[1:2], function(x) cust_lm(x, ydata))` is the correct answer. You can further simplify it as:

```
list <- lapply(names(ydata)[1:2], cust_lm, data=ydata)
```

This breaks down to "call `cust_lm` with each element of `names(ydata)[1:2]` in turn as first argument; use `ydata` for the argument named `data`".

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. Well, `list<-lapply(names(ydata)[1:2], function(z) cust_lm(z, data))' was a ** typo **. So, I can use either, `lapply(names(ydata)[1:2], function(z) cust_lm(z, data))` or `lapply(names(ydata)[1:2], cust_lm, data=ydata)`

Comment: But, when I call, `cust_lm` inside the list, how does that work? Because, arguments for that function are `varname` and `data`. But I am not giving the arugments exclusively inside lapply! Or in other words, can I use, `cust_lm` as an exclusive function? I am getting error when I use, `cust_lm(x, data[,y]`. Why is it so? Can you please clarify?

Comment: What do you mean by 'inside the list'? `cust_lm` assumes (based on it's two lines of code) that the object received in argument `data` has a column whose name is given by the argument `varname`.

Comment: I meant inside _lapply_. This helped clear my confusion.